# How do I fix line 42: [: too many arguments in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ksh

I have 1 script starting with `#!/bin/ksh`

Here is the code piece that create line 42: [: too many arguments

```
if  [ -f "$Log_dir/output.rej" ] && 
    [  grep -Hne "fails to validate" $Log_dir/output.rej >/dev/null ]
```

it expand to (set -xv)

```
+ '[' -f /export/home/xxxx/xsdlog/output.rej ']'
+ '[' grep -Hne 'fails to validate' /export/home/xxxx/xsdlog/output.rej ']'
TEST_VALIDATE.sh: line 42: [: too many arguments
```

I tried

```
if  [ -f $Log_dir/output.rej ] &&
    [  grep -Hne "fails to validate"   $Log_dir/output.rej >/dev/null ]
```

**without quotes("). The results same.**

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 8):

Stop trying to use the `[` command to execute another command.

```
if ... && grep ...
```

---

Example:

```
if  [ -f "$Log_dir/output.rej" ] && 
    grep -Hne "fails to validate" $Log_dir/output.rej >/dev/null
then
    ...
fi
```

Comment: How do we get good readability without '[', ']' ? Will same work with || (OR) ?

Comment: A backslash at the end of the line will continue it on the next line.

Comment: `&&` and `||` can be used to force continuations on the next line, so you don't need backslashes.